# Use reflection to find IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions> implementations

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to find all types that implement ASP.NET Core's `IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions>` interface.

Here is an example of such a class:

```cs
public sealed class MyJsonOptions : IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions> {
  public void Configure(JsonOptions options) { }
}
```

This found nothing:

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain
.GetAssemblies()
.Where(assembly => !assembly.IsDynamic)
.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.ExportedTypes)
.Where(type => type.IsAssignableTo<IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions>>())
.ToArray();
```

I also tried this:

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain
.GetAssemblies()
.Where(assembly => !assembly.IsDynamic)
.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.ExportedTypes)
.Where(type => type
  .GetInterfaces()
  .Any(x =>
    x.IsGenericType &&
    x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IConfigureOptions<>)))
    //&& x.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(JsonOptions)  // if included then nothing found
.ToArray();
```

That gives me all types implementing `IConfigureOptions<>`. But of course I also need the typeparam `JsonOptions.`

How do I do this?

Comment: @KlausGütter Updated

Comment: And you are really sure that there is at least one public type in any of the loaded assemblies implementing the interface?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes. If I search for it by name I can find it. Of course I need to do it dynamically without using names.

Comment: "Search by name" means replacing the last where by `.Where(type => type.Name == "xyz")`? Can you show the definition of the type in question?

Comment: Something like that. I answered your question about whether I am sure it's in the original set of types, and it is. I can find it in the debugger, and if I search for a specific type by name. So the types are there, but I can't filter for them. Well, almost, I can filter for the generic type, but don't know how to then filter by the typeparam as well.

Comment: Have you tried seaching by name using: `nameof(IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions>)`?

Comment: Any chance that the `JsonOptions` type in the `MyJsonsOptions` and the  `JsonOptions` in your query are in fact not the same type? You might perhaps try ` x.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name == "JsonOptions"`

Comment: @KlausGütter Wow! That worked. Kinda obvious when you think about it! I didn't realize there were multiple `JsonOptions` in the framework! If you add as an answer I'll close, thanks!

Comment: @KlausGütter You [are right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=JsonOptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the JsonOptions type in the MyJsonsOptions and the JsonOptions type in your query are in fact not the same type, there are at least two of them in .NET:

- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonoptions)
- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.json.jsonoptions)

So be sure to pick the right JsonOptions type in `.Where(type => type.IsAssignableTo<IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions>>())`.

(Or, alternatively, just compare by name `x.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name == "JsonOptions"`).

Comment: You are right, there [are two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=JsonOptions) `JsonOptions` types in the framework. Thanks!